# Summer program for 'international' undergraduate students of mathematics

Tags: undergraduate-education, curriculum, summer

I see that most of the american universities have mathematical summer programs with lectures and mini-courses (note: **I'm not talking about undergraduate *research* programs in this question**) for university students.

Unfortunately most of such programs are only for US citizens. So I would like to ask what summer programs are there in the US, Europe, Asia, South America, or Africa that are accessible to international students (note: in particular, I'm European)?

Comment: Are you sure they are not for non-domestic students, or, do you just refer to the lack of support from funding agencies? I do agree the lack of funding is a large impediment for international students seeking REUs. I never found a good solution and it is annoying as some of my best students are international. I realize some schools provide internal funds for such students, but, this is not universal.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Unfortunately, most of the programs I've found are for permanent residensts or US citizens only.

Comment: Are you just looking for an avenue to learn additional material, or, are you looking for a way to complete degree requirements for a degree somewhere?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook The first one.

Comment: The sister question about undergraduate summer research programs accessible to international students is probably also worth asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you like mathematical physics. There is a summer school in Bogotá, Colombia. http://matematicas.uniandes.edu.co/~cursillo_gr/escuela2015/index_en.php

Answer (score 1):

As you're discovered, many such summer programs are limited to US citizens and permanent residents; my understanding is that this is due to the source of their funding. Nonetheless, some programs exist which are accessible to international students. Unfortunately, since the funding source is what limits participants to US citizens/permanent residents, international participants might have to forgo funding, or pay. Here are the few programs I know of:

- [The Undergraduate Summer School at PCMI](https://pcmi.ias.edu/application-ugss): From their website,

> Undergraduates funded by PCMI may receive lodging, travel, meals and a
>   stipend (stipends are awarded to U.S. Citizens or U.S. permanent
>   residents only).

- [The EDGE program](http://www.edgeforwomen.org/summer-session/): From their website,

> Applicants to the program should be women who: 1) are applying to PhD
>   programs in the mathematical sciences, or 2) just completed their
>   first year in a PhD program in the mathematical sciences.
>
> Women from underrepresented minority groups are especially encouraged
>   to apply. Final acceptance to the program is contingent upon
>   enrollment in a PhD program in Fall 2015. Unfortunately, at this time
>   we are only able to fund US citizens and permanent residents.

- [SUAMI at Carnegie-Mellon](http://www.math.cmu.edu/cna/summer_institute_upcoming.html): From their website,

> U.S. citizens or permanent residents who are selected into the
>   program, will receive a stipend of $3,600, housing in the university
>   dormitories, and allowances for food and travel.
>
> Non U.S. citizens or non residents who are selected into the program,
>   will be expected to pay a registration fee of 4,000. In addition,
>   they are responsible for their own housing, travel and food.
>   University housing will be available for approximately $2,000 for the
>   duration of the Institute.

In addition, as mentioned in the comments (to the question) by James Cook, there might be sources of internal funding. If you are currently enrolled in a university, it is probably worthwhile to ask faculty members there.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but, as I said, I am searching for a program for undergraduates which includes lectures and mini-courses, but **I'm not searching for undergraduate *research* programs**.

Comment: @Dal The PCMI undergrad summer school consists roughly entirely of lectures as mentioned on their webpage. There is a component consisting of individual projects, which you can choose to be expository writing. The EDGE program consists entirely of lectures and mini-courses (along with mentoring opportunities), also listed on their website. From the SUAMI website: Participants "will spend eight weeks in Pittsburgh participating in a course in analysis, a computer laboratory, and working on projects under the direction of research faculty". Again, the primary components are courses and labs.